# Select and use only one solution in a list solutions

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

I would like to use and plot only one of the two solutions of a quadratic equation. In particular this is my equation

`msol=Solve[m[tau] Sqrt[1 + rr'[tau]^2] - m[tau]^2/(2 rr[tau]) - 1 == 0, m[tau]]`

with rr[tau] coming from another equation as an interpolating function. How do I select only one of the two solutions?

For instance, I have tried to do this to calculate the derivative of one of the two solutions

`mder = D[m[tau] /. msol[[2]], tau]`

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: `D[m[tau] /. msol[[2]], tau]` seems to work fine for me, returning `(Derivative[1][rr][tau] Sqrt[-2 + rr[tau] + 
   rr[tau] Derivative[1][rr][tau]^2])/(2 Sqrt[rr[tau]]) + (
 rr[tau] Derivative[1][rr][tau] (rr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[tau])/Sqrt[
 1 + Derivative[1][rr][tau]^2] + (
 Sqrt[rr[tau]] (Derivative[1][rr][tau] + Derivative[1][rr][tau]^3 + 
    2 rr[tau] Derivative[1][rr][tau] (rr^\[Prime]\[Prime])[tau]))/(
 2 Sqrt[-2 + rr[tau] + rr[tau] Derivative[1][rr][tau]^2])`

Comment: This is the error I get: `Part::partw: Part 2 of {{{m[tau]->InterpolatingFunction[{<<1>>},{<<13>>},{<<1>>},{<<3>>},{<<1>>}][tau] Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]-Sqrt[InterpolatingFunction[<<5>>][<<1>>]] Sqrt[Plus[<<3>>]]},{m[tau]->InterpolatingFunction[{<<1>>},{<<13>>},{<<1>>},{<<3>>},{<<1>>}][tau] Sqrt[Plus[<<2>>]]+Sqrt[InterpolatingFunction[<<5>>][<<1>>]] Sqrt[Plus[<<3>>]]}}} does not exist. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {{{{m[tau]->Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]},{m[tau]->Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]}}}[[2]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>`

Comment: Ahh, so `rr[tau]` is an interpolating function, possibly from a call to `NDSolve`?  That may be relevant

Comment: Yes JasonB, you are right, it is an interpolating function. I am going to edit my question specifying  this detail. Cheers